# Preventing DROP table in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server

Is there a way to prevent DROP TABLE in SQL Server somehow, simply by using SSMS and its features?

Comment: SSMS is just a piece of software that helps manage aspects of the server and the data. It does not and cannot control such things. You are looking for SQL Server features that will do so.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Don't give users permissions to drop tables.

You might think a [DDL trigger](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190989(v=sql.105).aspx) can *prevent* this. It does, in a way: it lets the drop happen, then it rolls it back. Which is not quite *preventing* it, but I suppose it might be good enough.

Comment: This answer would be better if it explained the process for adjusting permissions on a user to prevent them from being able to drop tables.

Answer (score 0):

Check [this](http://pratchev.blogspot.com/2007/12/prevent-table-drop.html) , There are two methods basically

> The first one is based on creating a view on the table with option
>   SCHEMABINDING. When the SCHEMABINDING option is used the table cannot
>   be modified in a way that will affect the view definition, as well as
>   it cannot be dropped unless the view is dropped first.
>
> The second method is using the new DDL triggers in SQL Server 2005.
>   Defining a trigger for DROP_TABLE with rollback in the body will not
>   allow dropping tables.

Comment: The view trick doesn't really prevent anything if the user can also drop the view. And I'd be careful about specifying that a DDL trigger will *prevent* it. It will roll it back, which if the drop takes a long time is not an instantaneous action. The only true way to prevent this is to control permissions.